# Show that $Y=\lfloor X\rfloor+1$ where $X$ is exponential is a geometric distribution?

Tags: probability-distributions

> Given the exponential distribution, $X$ with rate $\lambda$ define
>   $Y=\lfloor X\rfloor+1$. Show that $Y$ is geometric with
>   $p=1-e^{-\lambda}$.

**Work**

$$f(y) = P(Y=y)$$
$$=P(\lfloor X \rfloor + 1=y) $$
$$= P(\lfloor X \rfloor=y-1) $$
$$= P(y-1\leq X <y) $$
$$= \int_{y-1}^y\lambda e^{-\lambda x}dx $$
$$= [-e^{-\lambda x}]_{y-1}^y $$
$$= (e^{-\lambda})^y(e^\lambda-1)$$

Which is not correct. Could someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks

Comment: That is actually correct if you rearrange it.

Comment: $-e^{y \lambda}(1-e^\lambda)$ but isnt the negative sign out front wrong?

Comment: Aha but you want $(1-e^{-\lambda})$

Comment: @GeorgeDewhirst yes exactly

Comment: Shall I reveal it for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$ e^{-y\lambda}(e^{\lambda}-1) = e^{-(y-1)\lambda}(1-e^{-\lambda})$
$ = (1-p)^{y-1}p$

Comment: Of course. Not sure how I missed this. Thank you sir